# Explain @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

Can someone explain in simple terms what @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn does in Hibernate? I've read almost every reference on the internet but my concept is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

One use of this annotation I know is mapping inheritance strategy (table per class with JOIN).
Example:

If you have domain model with inheritance:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class BillingDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = Constants.ID_GENERATOR)
    protected Long id;

    @NotNull
    protected String owner;
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "CREDITCARD_ID")
public class CreditCard extends BillingDetails {

    @NotNull
    protected String cardNumber;

// other specific fields
}


@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "BANK_ID")
public class BankAccount extends BillingDetails {

    @NotNull
    protected String bankName;

// other specific fields
}
```

So you have three tables. **BANK_ID** and **CREDITCARD_ID** are primary keys for  **BANKACCOUNT** and **CREDITCARD** respectively. Moreover every key is foreign key that mapped to **ID** of **BILLINGDETAILS** table.
And this allow you to do polymorphic query. If you try this:

`select * from BillingDetails bd;`

Hibernate will do something like this:

```
SELECT BD.ID, BD.OWNER, CC.CARDNUMBER, BA.BANKNAME
 CASE
  WHEN CC.CREDITCARD_ID is not null then 1
  WHEN BA.ID is not null then 2
  WHEN BD.ID is not null then 0
 END
FROM
BILLINGDETAILS BD
left outer join CREDITCARD CC on BD.ID=CC.CREDITCARD_ID
left outer join BANKACCOUNT BA on BD.ID=BA.BANK_ID
```

This example from this [book](https://www.manning.com/books/java-persistence-with-hibernate-second-edition).